# Class error in create xml handler script in Php can any one have solution

Tags: php, xml, class, error-handling

```
$path = "n/";

class newDoc{
    public $doc;
    public $ta;
    
    function main($file=null){
        $this->doc = new DOMDocument();
        $this->doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $this->doc->formatOutput = true;
        if($file !== null){
        $this->doc->load($file);
        }
    return $this->doc;
    }
    
    function opentag($root,$name,$value=null){
        $this->ta = $this->doc->createElement($name,$value);
        $root->appendChild($this->ta);
        return $this->ta;
    }
    function setAtt($att,$value){
        $this->ta->setAttribute($att,$value);
    }
    function setDate(){
        $this->ta->setAttribute("time",date("h:i A"));
        $this->ta->setAttribute("day",date('d'));
        $this->ta->setAttribute("mon",date('m'));
        $this->ta->setAttribute("year",date('Y'));
    }
    function save($file){
        $this->doc->save($file);
    }
}

$doc = new newDoc();
$root = $doc->main();

$tag = $doc->opentag($root,"user","test");
$tag->setDate();


$doc->save($path."0.xml");
```

I try create this class for easy my work but i never good as well in php class please can any one help

Error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::setDate() in D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php:41 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 41

Comment: Well, it's like the error message says: there is no function setDate for an DOMElement. You defined this function for your class, so you should call it on the class variable!

Comment: I get this sulation before your answer

Comment: but I want to built a function like php DOMelements can I create in php class

Comment: You can extend the DOMDocument class and add your own functions there.